# What does TIOCGSERIAL is not supported mean?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, devices, serial-port, dmesg

Im writing a program, that sends data to a bluetooth device. The device is attached to my computer via /dev/rfcomm1. After numerous issues, I read the dmesg log, and saw:

TIOCGSERIAL is not supported

many times. What exactly does that mean? Does it mean if I get new bluetooth hardware, that operation will be supported? Is it a hardware problem? If I use my phone instead, might this still work?

Or is it referring to the device I am trying to connect?

If connecting to a bluetooth device via serial is a problem, what other methods exist?